# Unable to resolve service for type IEmailSender while attempting to activate RegisterModel

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity and I have a problem that I make a new example project and with individual authentication and scaffold identity 
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'MASQ.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There're two ways to do that :

1. remove the `services.AddDefaultTokenProviders()` in the `ConfigurureServices()` to disable `two-factor authentication (2FA)` :

   ```
   // file: `Startup.cs` :
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
       ///.AddDefaultTokenProviders(); /// remove this line
   ```
2. Add your own `IEmailSender` and `ISmsSender` implementation to DI contianer if you would like to enable `2FA`

   ```
   // file: `Startup.cs`

   services.AddTransient<IEmailSender,YourEmailSender>();
   services.AddTransient<IEmailSender,YourSmsSender>();
   ```

Edit:

<strike>Both should work.</strike>

Both should work for ASP.NET Core 2.1. However, as of ASP.NET Core 3.0, the first approach doesn't work any more.

Comment: i follow this [articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#debug) to solve it and it take me out to a new exception

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application

Comment: I urgently need that, when a user registerd an email send with a confirmation email

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah 1. have you registered you EmailSender in your DI container ? Does that work ?  2 . What did you do before the new exception of "Scheme already exists" happens ?

Comment: i follow my comment one articles
make a EmailSender Class 
make my startup according to the article
install the sendgrid package for email sender class 
i make the AuthMessageSenderOptions class

Comment: i follow my comment one [articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)
1.make a EmailSender Class 
2.make my startup according to the article
3.install the sendgrid package for email sender class 
4.make the AuthMessageSenderOptions class
5. commented  the **await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
** in register user method in register.cs.html

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah Could you please show us the `Startup.cs` and register-specific codes ?

Comment: Microsoft says if you used scaffolding, dont use .AddDefaultUI.. If you used migration, then add do.

Answer (score 51):

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.0 and had similar issue. I added the following .AddDefaultUI() to my Startup.cs & it worked.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }
```

Comment: I was missing : AddDefaultUI() Thank you.

Comment: Glad that helped

Comment: I don't want to use default UI, thus I can't add `AddDefaultUI`. Any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Awesome. Any idea WHY this worked?

Answer (score 11):

Add Default UI in the configuration service:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET Core 5.0 you can use the following code, instead of calling `AddIdentity`

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(
           option => {
               option.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
               option.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
               option.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
           })
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        //    options.UseSqlServer(
        //        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        //services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<Areas.Identity.Services.IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Adbullah , note that you registered a `Areas.Identity.Services.IEmailSender`. However , the identity need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender`

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's my time to be usefull. Since approach with green checkmark doesn't work in core 3.0 I have an idea. Basicaly you need to disable IEmailSender service. I think that not the best aproach, but if you dont need IEmailSender and you just want to quickly setup user functionality you can go to Register.cshtml.cs
and comment out (or delete) private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender; and everywhere it is used in this controller. Hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my Startup.cs & it worked.

> services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

Answer (score 0):

Have the same Error,
my Solution: Update Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI (Nuget)
to 8.0.0 (released today)  and it work's for me.

Package 8.0.0-rc.1.23421.29 or rc2 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test authentication and want to get things running and do not want to test the email confirmation part, this should work:

```
 services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
 {
     options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
   //... other options
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using net core 8.0, and for this issue I had to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` package and add `.AddDefaultUI();` to my `builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>`
.

```cs
// Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 12;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
.AddDefaultUI();
```

also I have `app.MapIdentityApi<AppUser>();`to map all auth enpoints.
and this fixed my issue.